# Dirichlet Sum over number of Divisors

Tags: divisor-sum

Dirichlet sum over number of divisors is

$$\sum_{k=1}^n{\tau(k)} = 2\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor{\sqrt n}\rfloor}\lfloor{\frac{n}{k}}\rfloor \ - {\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor}^2$$

What would be this formula for the sum

$$\sum_{k=1}^n{\tau(ak)}$$

if $a$ is a constant? I know I can't use the multiplicity property for $\tau(ak)$ unless $a$ and $k$ are relatively primes.

Comment: You meant the fact $\tau(k)$ is multiplicative. What about $f(k) = \frac{\tau(ak)}{\tau(a)}$ ?

Comment: @reuns If a and k share a common divisor other than 1 (e.g. 6 and 9), I can not take the constant out of the summation. The problem still.